# How to select a column per row based on multiple conditions in pandas

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe called df:

```
    Identifier   Name1   Name2     Country   Otherdata.......
0   N102314      BDH.A   0123      AUS
1   D19u248      DDF     DDF.X     DEN
2   J19j09f      XXG.X   XXG.DD    GER
3   Jd139jf      D07.SS  D07       SG
4   Jh39222      DEE     DEE.O     US
5   HH819jf      HHD.OH  HHD       MX
6   Jajh393      HXX     HXX.K     US  
7   DeeaJJd      MSS.O   DEX.O     US
```

I want to create a new column called Name0 where I select a column per row based on the following conditions.

If Country == "US", ALWAYS select what's in Name1 for Name0.

Otherwise, check which name contain a ".", and choose that item for Name0.
    if both of Name1 and Name2 contains a dot print the word NAMEERROR in Name0.

So the final frame will look like this:

```
    Identifier   Name1   Name2     Country  Name0      NOTES....... 
0   N102314      BDH.A   0123      AUS      BDH.A      #not US so chose the one with the "."
1   D19u248      DDF     DDF.X     DEN      DDF.X      #not US so chose the one with the "."
2   J19j09f      XXG.X   XXG.DD    GER      NAMEERROR  #not US and both contains ".", print NAMEERROR
3   Jd139jf      D07.SS  D07       SG       D07.SS     #not US so chose the one with the "."
4   Jh39222      DEE     DEE.O     US       DEE        #US so chose Name1
5   HH819jf      HHD.OH  HHD       MX       HHD.OH     #not US so chose the one with the "."
6   Jajh393      HXX     HXX.K     US       HXX        #US so chose Name1
7   DeeaJJd      MSS.O   DEX.O     US       MSS.O      #both contain "." but US so chose Name1
```

I was thinking it might look like for the first part

```
df['Name0'] = np.NaN
df['Name0'] = np.where(df['Country'].str.contains('US'),df['Name1'],df['Name0'])
```

but I don't know where to start for the rest of the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apply` is handy here.

```
def fix(country, n1, n2):
    if country == 'US':
        return n1
    else:
        if ('.' in n1) & ('.' in n2):
            return 'NAMERERROR'
        elif '.' in n1:
            return n1
        elif '.' in n2:
            return n2


df['Name0'] = df.apply(lambda x: fix(country=x['Country'],
                                     n1 = x['Name1'],
                                     n2 = x['Name2']), axis=1)
```

Comment: I get this error <ipython-input-214-f97f3003b3e1> in fix(country, n1, n2)
      5         return n1
      6     else:
----> 7         if ('.' in n1) & ('.' in n2):
      8             return 'NAMERERROR'
      9         elif '.' in n1:

TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

Comment: What are the datatypes of `Name1` and `Name2`? They need to be strings in order for this function to work. You can check by executing `df.dtypes`

Comment: Does df.dtypes show `object` for `Name1` and `Name2`?

Comment: okay it works now, I had to astype them before i merged it and after i merged it